# How to do role-based access in React?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net

I have an e-commerce site that I developed the backend part with asp.net core web api and the frontend with reactjs. I have generated jwt token in asp.net core web api and also I keep roles in user table in sql database There are two separate users as admin and user.And for example, I want to have areas that only the admin can access, such as adding colors and adding a brand on the react side, but even though I do authorize on the asp.net side, a person whose role is not an admin can add colors in react when they log in to the site. Do I need to do something extra in React for this? I don't know much about it, I just did things on the asp.net core web api side. Maybe they have a mistake. But it successfully generates the token and I can see the data in the token. what should i do about it?

**ColorController**

```
using BusinessLayer.Abstract;
using DataAccessLayer;
using EntityLayer.Concrete;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public class ColorController : Controller
    {

        IColorService _colorservice;
        DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();


        public ColorController(IColorService _colorservice)
        {
            this._colorservice = _colorservice;
        }

       
        [HttpGet("getall")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var colors = await _colorservice.TGetAll();

            if(colors != null)
            {
                return Ok(colors);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

        }


        [HttpPost("add")]
       
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Color color)
        {
            var result =_colorservice.TAdd(color);

            if (result != null)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            return BadRequest(result);
        }

     

    }
}
```

I said that only the admin can access the ColorController for testing purposes, but I did not do anything about it in the react part. When a non-admin person enters the react part, he can add color. How can I prevent this from happening. Do I need to open the token in react and check it according to the role data in it, if so, how can I do this? Or are there any other methods?

By the way, when the user logs in correctly, I send the token as a response in react.

**UserRepository**

```
 public async Task<string> Login(UserLoginDto logindto)
        {




            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
            var _user = await dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Mail == logindto.Mail).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (_user != null)
            {

                if ( (!_user.isLock) && ( _user.Password == crypto.Compute(logindto.Password, _user.salt) ))
                {


                    var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,_user.Mail),
                           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,_user.Name),
                           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname,_user.LastName),
                           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,_user.role),
                           

                           new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                    };
                    var authSigninKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                        audience: configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                        claims: authClaims,
                        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigninKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature));
                    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
                }
                else
                {
                    _user.LockCount +=1;
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    if(_user.LockCount >= 3)
                    {
                        _user.isLock = true;
                        dbContext.SaveChanges();
                        return "blockuser";
                    }
                    return "invalid";
                }
            }



            return "invalid";


        }
```

**EDIT**

I found something called jwt token decode for this, but I couldn't find how to access the role data here either.

role data where I want to reach

[image]

Comment: I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743498/role-based-react-router#:~:text=Define%20Roles%20and%20Permissions%20at,general%20and%20in%20react%20app.

Comment: i am getting it with jwt token so i need to check role data in jwt token. The answer you lead creates the roles in React. When the user logs in, I send that person's token to React and that token has the role of the logged in user, so I need to make a check based on that token.

Comment: I found something called jwt token decode for this, but I couldn't find how to access the role data here either.

Comment: Just an observation, make sure you don't make any authorization decision in the frontend (ie, use auth info only for UX enhancements) and leave all authorization logic to the backend.

Comment: Yes I understand you but as you can see in the colorcontroller above, I just added [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] and it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong or do I have something to add? I agree with you that it is better to do it in the backend. But here I am trying this method because I can't do it in the backend. But as I said backend, I did it this way, do you have any suggestions for me? where am i doing wrong?

Comment: I log in with the person whose postmande role is admin and after that I run the color add api, but even though the role is admin, 401Unauthorized
the same goes for the person whose role is not admin.